distrobox export binary with sudo access for rootless container
Can sudo be used for an exported distrobox app/binary in the host where its container is rootless?
Example:
I need to edit files in the root partition and admin permissions are required to access files.
vim ~/myfile.text
sudo vim /etc/nftables.conf

Scenario 1. using a rootless container
distrobox create ...
distrobox export --bin /usr/bin/vim --export-path ~/.local/bin --sudo

In the host, sudo vim doesn't work. Distrobox won't allow the use of sudo.
Scenario 2. using a rootful container
distrobox create ... --root
distrobox export --bin /usr/bin/vim --export-path ~/.local/bin --sudo

In the host, sudo vim works.
Some thoughts:

From what I've read, running a rootful container is not the best security practice. A process/potential malware within the container can have full access in the host.
I don't want to run multiple containers, i.e. one container which exports apps/bins with user permissions, and another container which exports apps/bins with admin permissions.

Shouldn't Scenario 1 (above) work? Am I missing something? I want a container which has binaries exported to the host which can be used normally, and also used with sudo when required.

after much research and trial & error I can confidently answer my own question. A rootless container runs under a user account and due to Linux file permissions, the user account isn't allowed access to system files!
What is required in this scenario is a rootfull container so the distrobox exported app has the required privileges to access the host system files.
Further, regarding security I would then use user namespaces and App Armour/SElinux to lock it down.
